# Поменять местами значения бинарного кода

Tags: c#

Нужно поменять местами значения бинарного кода например с 0111101 в 1011110. Пробовал через реверс, но эта зараза не только меняет местами значения, но еще и переводит с бинарного кода, а нужного только местами махнуть. Как сделать?

```
    static string Peremesh(ref string bin)
                {
                    char[] chak = bin.ToCharArray();
                    Array.Reverse(chak);
                    bin = new string(chak);
                    return bin;
                }

    static void Main()
    {
         string slov = ReadLine();
         var i = Binar(ref slov);
         WriteLine(i);
         var x = Peremesh(ref slov);//вызов метода
         WriteLine(x);
    }
static string Binar(ref string slovo)
        {
            string binresult = String.Empty;
            string asc = String.Empty;
            char[] arr = slovo.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char i in arr)
            {
                asc += (int)i;
                binresult += Convert.ToString(i, 2);
            }
            return binresult;
        }
```

Comment: Нужно познакомиться с битовыми операциями

Comment: С сожалению не знаком с ними пока.

Comment: Зачем вы передаете объект по со ссылке если вы возвращаете результат?

Comment: если объявить новую переменную строкой и вернуть ее, результат не измениться)))
я пробовал))

Comment: я просто перезаписываю bin и возвращаю ее обратно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите сделать с помощью строки, с вашим кодом  -

```
 static string Peremesh(ref string bin)
    {
        return new string(bin.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray()); 
    }
```

UPD: Выложили обновленный код, передавайте i в

```
Peremesh(ref i);
```

, так как ей присваивается бинарная строка, возвращаемая, при вызове метода

```
Binar(ref slov);
```

А вы передавали slov , т.е. строку - "колокол", а не ее бинарный эквивалент

Comment: Не помогло, та же самая история. Меняет местами символы и переводит с бинарника.

Comment: @Venen, покажите весь код ,результат вывода, и  что делаете после вызова функции, так как у меня все работает

Comment: мне бы не хотелось выкладывать целиком код.
После вызова ничего не делаю пока, потому что споткнулся тут. Разве что только это
var x = L_Peremesh(ref slov);
            WriteLine(x);

Comment: А результат вывода таков:
10000111010100001111101000011101110000111110100001110101000011111010000111011 //после преобразования слова колокол в бинарник.
локолок//после вызова Peremesh

Comment: @Venen , напишите еще в вопросе, код, как вы вызываете функцию и попробуйте, для теста  просто отдельно,  как строку, записать  string slov = "10000111010100001111101000011101110000111110100001110101000011111010000111011"; и передать ее

Comment: @GinTasan забавно, но по тесту как вы предложили все заработало. Вопрос только как сделать теперь все грамотно?

Comment: @Venen , откуда у вас slov появляется(видел, что после преобразования в бинарник, т.е , что это за функция, если она и что она возвращает и тд, можете даже выложить в вопрос) ? Проверьте значение, какой тип данных, возможно поймем в чем проблема

Comment: @GinTasan правил

Comment: @Venen , запустил на машинке, все проверил, ответ обновил

Comment: Мне даже и в голову не пришло что надо другую переменную вложить. Спасибо Большое!!! Помогло.

Comment: Не за что , обращайтесь и удачи в разработке